# Covariance of X and Y conditional on X+Y>Z?

Tags: random-variable, covariance, probability-inequalities, conditioning

Suppose that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are three independent random variables. Is there a way to compute the following conditional covariance?

$Cov(X, Y | X + Y \geq Z)$

Comment: Short answer: of course. If you are looking for anything more informative than that, please provide some context and details that describe what you know about the trivariate distribution and in what form that information is in.